Unable to Track New Files and Folders in Git with VS Code
I cloned my Git repository in VS Code, and while I can commit and push changes to existing files, new files or folders I create aren’t recognized. When I run git status, it says my branch is up to date, and I don’t see any options in the Source Control panel for the new files.
What I’ve Tried:

Checked that new files are in the cloned repository directory.
Reviewed the .gitignore file for exclusions.
Reloaded VS Code.

Why isn’t Git recognizing my new files and folders?
How can I add them to my repository and push them to GitHub?

Git doesn't add new files automatically. You have to add them (with git add).

You could try git status --ignored to list all files that are ignored. Or git check-ignore <filename> to see if the file is ignored or not (returning blank means it is not ignored).

Maybe because the folder is in safe mode?
